# Shift camera focus on the same path

Tags: camera, constraints, path

I want to make a scene of planets where in my camera would move on set path in random circles around the planets. Now I have set a path to make circular motions and also a linked camera on the path. The issue now is that, with the constraints which I put on the camera, I can only put one planet in the target and during the whole motion camera will always be focusing at it. I want to make the camera focus move to second planet and then the third and then onwards. I tried to use camera rotation focusing on another planet and then made a keyframe on that rotation but that doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Is there a way to use one path and move focus on different frames to other planets/objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem and solved it by having an invisible object or "Empty" constrained to the path, and then had the camera parented to that.
I scrolled the timeline cursor to wherever I wanted the camera to look at any particular object and recorded the keyframes.  You don't have to be all that acurate when setting the camera's aiming up because it's a simple matter to try it all out and adjust the camera at those or additional keyframes later.

The keyframes themselves can be advanced or brought back in the dope sheet.  Extra keyframes will hold the cam aimed at each object as it follows the parent.  If desired you can also Switch views with that same camera as though operating more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is very easy way. Give the camera, one "Track to" constraint for each planet, that You want the camera focus on, and then Animate Influence of the constraints.
Although if You want different planets to be in camera focus in Depth of field settings, You need to create an empty, make it focus target and "Track to" target and give it "Copy Location" constraint for every planet. Then Animate influence of "Copy Location" constraints of this empty.

Comment: Thanks guys , your answers were right on the dot and I even got a youtube link for the same https://youtu.be/6Uj-rRZorKY